# Не работает Blur в FF

Tags: css, blur

Собственно вопрос, не работает blur в firefox.
[ссылка на сайт](http://tsvg.ndv.ru/ipoteka.php), выкладываю на сайт по той причине, что на jsfiddle все отлично работает. 
Svg добавил, а толку 0. 
Может вы что увидите...

```css
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.blur_h {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: url(#blur);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur_h">
  <img class="bg" src="http://tsvg.ndv.ru/img/bg5.jpg">
</div>
<img id="bg5" class="bg" src="http://tsvg.ndv.ru/img/bg5.jpg">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Инспектор в ФФ говорит, что "could not load the image", похоже, он не понимает ссылки типа url(#blur)

Comment: А как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеры по-разному воспринимают свойство url(...) без явного указания пути.

Если продублировать стили с фильтрами в `<head>` или добавить через тот же jquery `$('.blur').css('filter','url(#blur)');`, всё заработает.

Но при использовании на сайте `ajax` `pjax` и изменении контента с эффектами svg, приходится или обновлять для браузера тег `style`, или добавлять через javascript.

Comment: О, заработало. Спасибо